# g++10's feature testing fails on __cpp_lib_span

Tags: c++, g++, c++20

The MCVE below tests whether the compiler (g++10) supports spans, but gives the wrong answer.

```
#ifndef __cpp_lib_span
#warning "This compiler does not support spans."
#endif

#include <span>

int main(void)
{
    int i[10]; 
    std::span s(i);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints the warning (below), but  then goes on to load `<span>` and use spans. Spans seem to work fine in less minimal programs too. g++ is fine with recognizing that it does support concepts (`__cpp_concepts`). Am I doing something wrong, or have I found a compiler bug?

```
main.cpp:2:2: warning: #warning "This compiler does not support spans." [-Wcpp]
    2 | #warning "This compiler does not support spans."
```

Answer (score 6):

The `_cpp_lib_*` macros aren't predefined macros according the standard (unlike `_­_­cpp_­concepts`). The list of pre-defined macros is at [[cpp.predefined]](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined).

Library feature test macros require the inclusion of a header. `__cpp_lib_span` gets defined when including `<version>` or `<span>`.

You didn't include either prior to checking if the macro is defined, so it's not incorrect behavior for it to be undefined at that point.

Comment: Is there a way to give this warning, then? If I put it afterward, compilation is terminated and it never reaches the #warning directive.

Comment: @TopologicalSort - I confess that I don't understand the issue. Even if you could give the warning, compilation would still terminate shortly after.

Comment: @TopologicalSort - Wait, what does crashing have to do with it? Code that won't build can't crash. The long and short of it is that you can either rely on the value of `__cplusplus` (though special will need to be taken when compiling in MSVC) to assume span is available, or simply go the safe route and provide a single solution that doesn't require C++20.

Comment: I can't edit my comment, so I will recreate it here with appropriate edits. >> I want to make code that works on different platforms. If the platform is C++20-capable, I want it to run spans. If it's not, I want it to give a warning and solve the problem a different way.I don't want users to see *it fail to compile* and assume I have buggy code.

Comment: I will look into using __cplusplus soon as I can.

Comment: @TopologicalSort Don't use `__cplusplus`, it's way too coarse to be useful. What're you actually trying to do? This answer is correct - `#include <version>` and then check the macro.

Comment: @TopologicalSort - While I'm still not entirely sure if it's your exact problem, if your issue is that of checking for header existence prior to inclusion, then C++17 added [`__has_include`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include). It doesn't mean the header won't cause errors when included, but at least it will eliminate some guesswork. I'm afraid supporting multiple standard versions while employing new library features can be a bit tricky prior to C++20 and `<version>`.

Comment: The `__has_include` works. In all platforms I currently have access to, either span is supported and has the library include, or it's not supported and has no such include (which surely makes sense). Post that as your answer and I will gratefully accept it.

Comment: @TopologicalSort - That's not an answer to the question you **asked**. That's something I had to work from the crumbs you were providing.

Comment: @TopologicalSort checking `__has_include(<span>)` is not a good idea, since compiler vendors can and do ship non-functional headers. Including `<version>` (or `<ciso646>`) and checking the feature test macro is the correct solution.